# Issues while making ESP8266 as web server

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I have programmed `ESP8266` with below program. I used USB to TTL convert to program `ESP8266`. This is how I wired my circuit:

USB TTL---------------- ESP8266 ESP-01

GND-----------------------GND

TX---------------------------RX

RX---------------------------TX

3.3V-----------------------VCC & CH_PD

GND------------GPIO0

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "shiv";//type your ssid
const char* password = "manmohan@12345";//type your password

WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

  // Print the IP address
  Serial.print("Use this URL to connect: ");
  Serial.print("http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/");

}

void loop() {
  // Check if a client has connected
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }

  // Wait until the client sends some data
  Serial.println("new client");
  while(!client.available()){
    delay(1);
  }

  // Read the first line of the request
  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.println(request);
  client.flush();

  // Match the request

  int value = LOW;
  if (request.indexOf("/LED=ON") != -1) {
    value = HIGH;
  } 
  if (request.indexOf("/LED=OFF") != -1){
    value = LOW;
  }


  // Return the response
  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println(""); //  do not forget this one
  client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
  client.println("<html>");

  client.print("Led pin is now: ");

  if(value == HIGH) {
    client.print("On");  
  } else {
    client.print("Off");
  }
  client.println("<br><br>");
  client.println("Click <a href=\"/LED=ON\">here</a> turn the LED on pin 2 ON<br>");
  client.println("Click <a href=\"/LED=OFF\">here</a> turn the LED on pin 2 OFF<br>");
  client.println("</html>");

  delay(1);
  Serial.println("Client disonnected");
  Serial.println("");

}
```

It was successful, here are the logs:

```
Archiving built core (caching) in: C:\Users\williams~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_375631\core\core_esp8266_esp8266_generic_CpuFrequency_80,FlashFreq_40,FlashMode_dio,UploadSpeed_115200,FlashSize_512K64,ResetMethod_ck,Debug_Disabled,DebugLevel_None_____feb0d75f3cf4e05271af4f91549cd009.a
Sketch uses 230073 bytes (52%) of program storage space. Maximum is 434160 bytes.
Global variables use 32376 bytes (39%) of dynamic memory, leaving 49544 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
Uploading 234224 bytes from C:\Users\williams~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_189179/sketch_may14d.ino.bin to flash at 0x00000000
................................................................................ [ 34% ]
................................................................................ [ 69% ]
.....................................................................            [ 100% ]
```

Once this was completed, I opened serial monitor and it was empty there, baud rate was 115200. It is weird, Isn't ?

I followed this tutorial https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/ROBINTHOMAS/esp8266-esp-01-webserver-7248ca and on serial monitor it should be like below snapshot. What wrong I am doing ? Can anyone help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tying GPIO0 to ground puts the ESP into programming mode, allowing you to flash it.  To actually run the code, pull it high - that is, disconnect it from ground and connect a resistor (about 10k) between GPIO0 and +3.3v.

Do the same with RST.

Comment: I disconnected GPIO0 to ground, then restarted Arduino software then selected port COM5 then open serial monitor then still same result .. here is my settings http://imgur.com/a/kT4kS

Comment: Here is serial monitor snapshot http://imgur.com/a/T4tXg

Comment: You might need to pull it high, as I explained in the answer. You might also need to pull RST high in the same way.

Comment: Thanks! I resolved it by connecting with Arduino, it worked :) +1

Comment: Could you explain what you did please, for my interest and for future reference?

Comment: I have posted an answer how I resolved it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Mark Smith. I used UART to flash new firmware to `ESP8266`. I connected Arduino and ESP8266 in this way to test `ESP8266` new firmware:

Arduino ---------------- ESP8266 ESP-01

GND-----------------------GND

TX---------------------------TX

RX---------------------------RX

3.3V-----------------------VCC & CH_PD

Then I opened Serial Monitor on 115200 baud rate and it started to work as expected. Cheers!